# How to invoke child class method from parent class through reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I want to create a menu which should be populated by arbitrary methods, which are marked by an annotation. The methods should be invoked from inside the base class. Unfortunately 'java.lang.ClassCastException' is thrown since the `method.invoke` function expects an object which is instance of the child class. But i only get the base class.

Here is what i tried so far :

```
public abstract Class BaseClass{

    private void invokeSomeMethod(){
        final Method[] methods= getClass().getDeclaredMethods();

        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(MenuFunction.class)) {
                MenuFunction menuFunction = method.getAnnotation(MenuFunction.class);
                menuFunction.invoke(this); //Throws 'java.lang.ClassCastException' 
            }
        }
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ METHOD })
    public @interface MenuFunction {
        String Label();
    }

}

public Class ChildClass extends BaseClass{

     @MenuFunction(Label = "First method")
    public void setHigh(){
      //Arbitrary function 
    }

    @MenuFunction(Label = "Another method")
    public void setLow(){
      //Do something
    }

}
```

Comment: what's `Class ChildClass()`? it's not Java

Comment: Thanks was mistake, corrected

Comment: `menuFunction.invoke(this);` you are trying to invoke annotation?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is this:

public abstract class BaseClass {

```
public void invokeSomeMethod() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    final Method[] methods = getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(MenuFunction.class)) {
            MenuFunction menuFunction = method.getAnnotation(MenuFunction.class);
            method.invoke(this); //invoke method here'
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ChildClass extends BaseClass{

    @MenuFunction(Label = "hello")
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

        new ChildClass().invokeSomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Result:

hello

Comment: I would need to put in any child class. I am looking for a more generic solution. The methods marked with the annotation shall appear in a menu in the ui later, just by deriving the class and add the annotation .